# all data variables in the same row CSV with Python

Tags: python, csv, row

```
# coding=utf-8
# Libreria RegEx de Python.
import re
# Libreria para rutas.
import os
import csv

# function betwwen: return the value between two words a and b
def between(value, a, b):
    pos_a = value.find(a)  # Find and validate before-part.
    if pos_a == -1: return ""  # Find and validate after part.
    pos_b = value.rfind(b)
    if pos_b == -1: return ""  # Return middle part.
    adjusted_pos_a = pos_a + len(a)
    if adjusted_pos_a >= pos_b: return ""
    return value[adjusted_pos_a:pos_b]

# function scan folder DiarioOficial
def scan_folder():
    # directory 'path'
    path = '/Users/anna/PycharmProjects/extractData/DiarioOficial'
    # contador de ficheros del path
    count = 0

    # creation csv as csvFile
    with open('All_Companies1.csv', 'a') as csvFile:
        # iterate all paths in the folder DiarioOficial without name
        for (path, dirnames, file_names) in os.walk(path):
            # iterate over all the files in the path (+ file_name)
            for file_name in file_names:
                # Add extension that is required
                if file_name.endswith(".txt"):
                    # summatory count files in DiarioOficial folder
                    count = count + 1
                    # concatenation path + file name
                    file_path=os.path.join(path, file_name)
                    #print(file_path)
                    # open and read the file path
                    mensaje = open(file_path).read()
                    # Replace a newline for a space
                    mensaje = mensaje.replace("\n","")

                    # Company Name
                    keywords_cap = ['SpA', 'SPA', 'LIMITADA', 'LTDA', 'S.A.', 'E.I.R.L.', 'S.L.']
                    # re.escape to solve the problem with metacharacters in keyword_obj
                    keywords_cap = map(re.escape, keywords_cap)
                    # sorting the items by lengh in descending order
                    keywords_cap.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
                    obj = re.compile(r'[:,;.]\s*"?([^:,;.]*?(?<!\w)(?:{}))'.format('|'.join(keywords_cap)))
                    if obj:
                        # To obtain the first match obj.search(mensaje).group(1)
                        company_name = obj.search(mensaje)
                    else:
                        company_name = "None"

                    # CVE Number of the file
                    regex = r"\s*CVE\s+([^|]*)"
                    matches = re.search(regex, mensaje)
                    if matches:
                        company_cve = matches.group(1).strip()
                    else:
                        company_cve = "None"

                    # Section of diariooficial.interior.gob.cl
                    company_sect = between(mensaje, 'SECCIÓN', 'Núm.')
                    if company_sect:
                        company_sect = company_sect
                    else:
                        company_sect = "None"

                    # Name of the person that constitutes the company
                    company_ceo = re.search(r'\sante mí,\s+([^,]*)', mensaje)
                    if company_ceo:
                        company_ceo = company_ceo.group(1)
                    else:
                        company_ceo = "None"

                    # File Number from Section
                    num_reg = r'\sNúm.\s+([^|]*)'
                    match_num = re.search(num_reg, mensaje)
                    if match_num:
                        company_numsect = match_num.group(1)
                    else:
                        company_numsect = "None"

                    # Social Capital ($)
                    cap = r"\s*(CAPITAL:\s+([^-]*)|Capital social:\s+([^-]*)|Capital:\s+([^-]*)|Capital:\s+([^,]*))"
                    caps = re.search(cap, mensaje)
                    if caps:
                        company_capital = caps.group()
                    else:
                        company_capital = 'None'

                    csvData = [company_name, company_cve, company_sect, company_ceo, company_numsect, company_capital]
                    headers = ['COMPANY NAME', 'CVE', 'SECTION','CEO NAME','NUMBER SECTOR','COMPANY CAPITAL']
                    writer = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter=',') # create a csv delimited by comma
                    writer.writerow(headers)  # print the header row
                    writer.writerow(csvData)  # print the Data in csv
            # Number of txt files
            print (count)
scan_folder()
```

I have this script that create a csv with the data extracted from a text in specific path. In spite of the errors that can be on RegEx, mainly it extracts parts of text that it keeps them in variables and the printa in a csv. Each company must have a single line in this csv. In this way, when the csv is opened, the number of companies and all the information can be visualized by variables.

My problem is that when I see the CSV called, in this case, All_companies1, the data is not put in the same row, they jump.

Also, the titles are repeated, and I do not want them to repeat themselves

[image: Also, the titles are repeated, and I do not want them to repeat themselves.]

Comment: Try using pandas. you could do everything in just 1 line of code. pandas.read_csv() see doc https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try changing the mode for the `csvFile` from `a` (append) to `w` (write), also check if the editor you're using actual uses the comma as the column delimiter for `csv` files, since in the above picture is seems as if the comma is seen by the editor as a normal character.

Also remove any carriage return characters (`\n \r`) from your string before printing it, this can be done in the following code.

`csvData = [str(data).replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '') for data in csvData]`

Note: 
if by any chance this works, there might be a problem with with having empty rows in the `csv` file beteen each two elements, this can be fixed by changing `with open('All_Companies1.csv', 'a') as csvFile` to `with open('All_Companies1.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvFile`

Comment: The editor that I am using uses the comma as delimiter for CSV, this is not the problem. I have done what you have told me and it does work, but the headers are repeated by company (or rather, each line). The problem was that I was replacing the '\n' before operating with the data, to be able to debug them, but I did not save the format when I entered it in the CSV. Besides, now the CSV repeat headers each line that I create a new iteration of a company.

Comment: Also, I have another problem but with RegEx. When I print the value of company_name the output of the majority companies are <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x103204d50>. When I put the regex equation in another script without the iterations, it works correctly. Why can that be? How can I solve this problem? Moreover in another equations of Regex also happens... but to a greater extent only in the name of the company (variable: company_name)

Comment: I put another question relation with this final problem with SRE_Match and convert to string. Thank you for your answer!! @Bara'Hashesh